# Limit text width

Tags: html, css, text

Long inputs in my site overflow out of the div and the allowed width.

I read that it's because the browser will only insert line breaks if there are spaces.

Since my site is all about user-input, that could mess up with things.

I wanted to know if there's a way to still limit the width even if the input has no spaces in it.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your div scrollable so all overflowing content doesn't break the layout but scrolls instead.

```
 <div style="overflow:scroll;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recomend you to use `overflow:auto` instead, to your div. It may give you better result.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, word wrap breaks lines on word boundaries. If you don't have word boundaries, then that's going to be an issue.

So don't rely on word-wrap, but make your containers scrollable with `overflow: scroll` and friends in CSS.